# "There's a difference.": "Being?" or "Being what?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Michael denies the truth that horse racing is the only vice for Lord George.

> Michael: I've always taken vice to be the definition of any criminal 
>   activity or wicked behavior involving prostitution, pornography or
>   drugs, so, no...racing is definitely not your only vice,  your
>   lordship. I'd say you're eyebrows deep in every vice known to man.
>
> Lord George: There is a difference.
>
> Michael: **Being**?
>
> Lord George: I facilitate. I don't participate in any of the
>   aforementioned vices.

Is the word "what" after "being" not necessary ?

I find these lines in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference to the phrase *the difference being that...*, a not uncommon way of introducing an explanation of why two things are different.  See https://ludwig.guru/s/the+difference+being+that

Lord George doesn't say what the difference is until he is prompted by one word from the familiar phrase.

Comment: Similarly, you could have Michael saying 'Namely?' or 'That is?'.